# How to write a good aircraft maintenance work card?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

Is there any guidance for writing the aircraft maintenance work cards? I want to find out some articles or books talking about this topic as I just start new job on it. How to write a good aircraft maintenance work card?

Comment: Have a look at ATA Spec 100 and ATA Spec 2200. 100 can easily be found on google.

Comment: Not specific to aircraft maintenance, but here are some pointers for writing about technical subjects: https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9247/what-are-best-practices-when-writing-technical-descriptions/9281#9281